# Mocking GraphQL, MockList genertes only two items in the array

Tags: javascript, mocking, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to generate a list of 10 items in my GraphQL mock server like this:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema, addMockFunctionsToSchema, MockList } from 'graphql-tools';
import casual from 'casual';
import typeDefs from './schema.graphql';

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs });

const mocks = {
  File: () => ({
    path: casual.random_element([
      '/assets/images/cars/1.JPG',
      '/assets/images/cars/2.JPG',
      '/assets/images/cars/3.JPG',
      '/assets/images/cars/4.JPG',
      '/assets/images/cars/5.JPG',
      '/assets/images/cars/6.JPG',
      '/assets/images/cars/7.JPG',
    ]),
  }),
  UsedCar: () =>
    new MockList(10, () => ({
      price: casual.integer(10000, 99999999),
      year: casual.integer(1990, 2017),
    })),
};

// This function call adds the mocks to your schema!
addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema, mocks });
```

But I always get two used cars I don't know why.
Can anyone help?

Regards,
Mostafa

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your code, you are defining a mock resolver for your UsedCar type. You didn't post your typeDefs or resolvers, but I'm guessing your type definition for UsedCar includes the two fields (price and year)... not a whole array of objects with those two fields. However, that is what you are telling the mock function you have.

If you have a query that fetches an array of `UsedCar` types, in order to get 10 mocked objects of that type, you will have to mock both the query **and** the type. So, assuming you have a query like `getUsedCars`, what you really want is:

```
mocks: {
  Query: () => ({
    getUsedCars: () => new MockList(10)
  }),
  UsedCar: () => ({
    price: casual.integer(10000, 99999999),
    year: casual.integer(1990, 2017),
  })
}
```

**Edit:** If you **only** mock the type, anywhere in the schema that resolves to an array of that type will return two mocked objects by default, which is why you were seeing two instead of ten.

Comment: thanks got it working it was part of another graphql type
  UsedCarQuery: () => ({
    find: () => new MockList(12),
  }),

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, mocking the Query as well was the trick!

Comment: @Shalkam Did you have to add custom resolvers to be able to use 'getUsedCars' function during Mocking? I have a similar use case, where I am trying to return more than 2 objects but it doesn't seem to work.
addMocksToSchema({
                    schema: apiSchema,
                    mocks: mockedSchema,
        })

Comment: Does anybody know how to return custom objects with specific values? Say I need array of 2 object, one to have {price: 100, year: 2000}, another {price: 200, year: 2010} ?