# GraphQL with mock data unable to query all results

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am a newbie to to GraphQL and am looking for some help. I am trying to create six user objects, and query all six objects, but I am only seeing two when I do the query. Can anyone please help?

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
const { importSchema } = require("graphql-import");
const { MockList } = require("graphql-tools");
const casual = require("casual");

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = importSchema("./schema.graphql");
// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => "Hello world!"
  }
};

const mocks = {
  Query: () => ({
    Member: () => new MockList([0, 6])
  }),
  Member: () => ({
    id: casual.integer(0),
    name: casual.full_name,
    username: casual.username,
    sourceAddress: casual.numerify("+1##########"),
    email: casual.email,
    gender: casual.random_element(["Male", "Female"])
  })
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  mocks
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

and the query I am typing is

```
query{
  feed{
    name
  }
}
```

I get these results

```
{
  "data": {
    "feed": [
      {
        "name": "Kenyon Reilly"
      },
      {
        "name": "Allan Collier"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/jz9w42v0py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking GraphQL, MockList genertes only two items in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000522/mocking-graphql-mocklist-genertes-only-two-items-in-the-array)

Comment: As noted in the accepted answer for the question above, `mocks.Query` should return an object with a `feed` property, which itself should be a function that returns the `MockList` instance. `feed` is the field on `Query` you are mocking, not `Member`